# css animation not working first time in any browser

Tags: html, css, css-animations

animation is not working on first load here http://sbarrogrimsby.com/

pizza is scrolled down from right to left under menu (next to handmade fresh all way). but when we refreshed page, it is working.

html code:
    
css code used:

```
.grape_pizza
{
width:915px; 
height:921px; 
position:absolute; 
right:-15%; 
 bottom:-75px;background:url("../images/banner_image.png") no-repeat top center;  
-webkit-animation: webkit-circle 2s linear 1;
-moz-animation: moz-circle 2s linear 1; 
-o-animation: o-circle 2s linear 1;   
-ms-animation: ms-circle 2s linear 1; 
-o-animation: circle 2s linear 1; 
animation:circle 2s linear 6; 
-ms-transform-origin: 50% 50px; 
-o-transform-origin: 50% 50px; 
-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50px; 
-moz-transform-origin: 50% 50px; 
transform-origin: 50% 50px; 
border-radius:50%;
}

@-webkit-keyframes webkit-circle {
    from{-webkit-transform:rotate(270deg);}
    to {-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes moz-circle {
    from{-moz-transform:rotate(270deg);}
    to {-moz-transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
 @-ms-keyframes ms-circle {
    from{-ms-transform:rotate(270deg);}
    to {-ms-transform:rotate(360deg);}
}  

 @-o-keyframes o-circle {
    from{-o-transform:rotate(270deg);}
    to {-o-transform:rotate(360deg);}
}  
 @keyframes circle {
    from{transform:rotate(270deg);}
     to {transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
```

Comment: While it is good that you included the relevant CSS in the question itself, it would be much better if you could create a demo (either using Stack Snippets or JSFiddle or CodePen). Users generally (or atleast I) don't prefer having to visit external sites to analyze the problem and then create a demo by themselves using code from the site. (*Note:* Using the code provided in question, I couldn't reproduce the issue on Chrome).

Comment: I think what may be happening is that the graphic is _still loading_ while the animation runs. When I clear my cache, I see only half the pizza sometimes on reloading the page. If that is the problem you're experiencing, might I suggest starting the animation only after everything is loaded (i.e. in the onload event).